# AJAX form POSTING even after it is disabled

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two forms that are posting data to another page using AJAX, the first form is posting the data fine, but the second form refreshes the page

I've tried placing the JavaScript for the second form in another file, or in the header using a  tag, but that doesn't help either.

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var form = $('#form1');   
form.submit(function(event){

    var data1= $('#data1').val(); 
    var data2= $('#data2').val(); 

    $.post('includes/page2.inc.php', {data1: data1, data2: data2}, function(data){
        $('#div').html(data);
    });
}
event.preventDefault();
});

    var form2 = $('#form2');
    form2.submit(function(event){
        var data3= $('#data3').val(); 
        var data4= $('#data4').val(); 
        $.post('page2.inc.php', {data3: data3, data4: data4}, function(data){
            $('#div').html(data);
        });
    }
event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" action = "" method = "POST">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-3" >
                    <label style="padding: 2px;">Option 1</label>
                    <select class="custom-select" id="data1" name="select1">
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="form-row modmarginleft">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <label style="padding: 2px;">Option 2</label>
                    <select class="custom-select" id="data2" name="select2">
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="btn1">
                <button type="submit" name="btn1" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin: 10px;" value="">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>


<form id = "form2" action = "" method = "POST">
        <div class="form-row ">
            <div class="col-3" style="padding:10px;">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="data3" type="checkbox" value="">  Option 1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3" style="padding:10px;">
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="data4" type="checkbox" value="">  Option 2</label>
            </div>
        </div><br>
        <div class="btn1">
            <button type="submit" name="btn2" id = "btn13" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin: 10px;" value="">Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I want 'form2' to not POST after it is submitted which it is currently doing, The first form submits without posting *if* I remove the code for the second form, but it POSTS like normal if I include it.

I forgot to mention in my post and I don't know if this matters, but the second form is in another file.

EDIT : Issue resolved by binding the document(page2.php) to the submission of the second form

Comment: To my eye it looks like the above is either incorrect or missing something. Can you confirm whether or not you omitted something when pasting and creating the question?

Comment: Can you update question with html markup?

Comment: @RamRaider The javascript code? because I may have mistyped during editing the post

Comment: is the 2nd piece missing the `$(document).ready(function(){`?? Why make two ajax requests - you could either use a `FormData` object and append values from both forms or create your own object with values from each form

Comment: Use a tool like https://jshint.com/ - it will point out your errors.

Comment: @Admir added HTML

Answer (score -1):

form2 doesn't work properly because it is outside your `$(document).ready` function.

Also, `event.preventDefault()` should be within each form's submit function.
Overall, your code should look something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = $('#form1');
    form.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var data1= $('#data1').val();
        var data2= $('#data2').val();

        $.post('includes/page2.inc.php', {data1: data1, data2: data2}, function(data){
            $('#div').html(data);
        });

    });

    var form2 = $('#form2');
    form2.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();  
         var data3= $('#data3').val();
        var data4= $('#data4').val();
        $.post('page2.inc.php', {data3: data3, data4: data4}, function(data){
            $('#div').html(data);
        });

    });
});
```